# What was the movie Tom referred to when arguing with Chris?

Tags: parks-and-recreation

In the *Parks and Recreation* episode Operation Ann (S04E14), Chris Traeger was responsible for DJing in a Valentine's Day party. He was playing horrible music and this conversation happened between him and Tom Haverford:

> **Tom:** Hey Chris Cross, can we change up the music? It kinda sounds like the
>   end of a movie about a monk who killed himself.
>
> **Chris:** It is.

Are they referring to an actual movie? What is it? [You can see the scene [here](http://parksandrecreation.wikia.com/wiki/File:Parks_And_Recreation_Operation_Ann_-_Clip_1).]

Comment: Can't support this claim in any way, but I'm guessing it's just a joke.

Comment: The first movie I thought of when I saw that the first time was [The Name of the Rose](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0091605/) however, that movie isn't about a monk that kills himself. The soundtrack is somewhat similar but I am unable to say that is the movie. More likely, it is from a movie about a Tibetan monk self immolating himself, but I can't support that claim either.

Comment: If referring to a movie, wouldn't he use "the movie" instead of "a movie"?

Comment: @Lettmannen Tom is only rhetorically positing such a movie; Chris is the one who's saying it's real.

Comment: Well that's my point. That if Tom would be referring to an actual movie, he would have used "The" article. Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @Lettmannen I think the title confused you. Tom didn't refer to a specific movie when he said that. He just thought the music could be good in any movie about a monk who killed himself. Chris did refer to the movie when he agreed with Tom. When Chris said "It is", it was like he said "There is such a movie".

Comment: Tom doesn't recognize the music as being from a specific movie. He is simply saying it sounds like it could be from a movie out of many movies that is about a monk who kills himself. The humor and irony comes when Chris affirms that it is in fact from a movie about a monk who kills himself.

Answer (score 7):

## Kundun

This [Fader article](http://www.thefader.com/2012/05/03/footnotes-philip-glass-scores) seems certain that the music is from Philip Glass's score of Kundun, the 1997 Martin Scorsese film about the Dalai Lama. A monk died in it, though I don't think he killed himself. The young Dalai Lama has visions of many dead monks as well,

Listening to the [Clip from Parks and Rec](http://parksandrecreation.wikia.com/wiki/File:Parks_And_Recreation_Operation_Ann_-_Clip_1) I originally thought it was the track [Lhasa at Night](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gd39A4pF-HI), due to the horns, but there is no gong in this track even though the rest of it sounds pretty similar to me. Currently listening to the album to see if I can find a better match.

Answer (score -1):

Its referring to a movie about a monk named [*Thích Quảng Đức*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%ADch_Qu%E1%BA%A3ng_%C4%90%E1%BB%A9c), i suggest you guys read about it, really good read :)

Comment: Is there anything else you could possibly add to this answer? We are looking for long answers on this site, it isn't compulsory; but it is a good idea, maybe refer to the help centre for more help on that. Good try though!

Comment: Welcome to Movies.SE! Could you explain this answer a little more? What was the name of the film, and why do you believe it's a match?

Answer (score -2):

While it is impossible to prove a negative, I believe there is no such movie and the entire exchange was just a joke.